# Spring Cloud Dataflow and scheduled tasks

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Spring Cloud Dataflow installed on an Openshift cluster. I try to register an application, then to create a task, and everything is fine, but when I try to schedule the task I got the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create directory for local repository: ?/.m2/repository
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.(MavenArtifactResolver.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenResource.(MavenResource.java:122) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenResource.parse(MavenResource.java:268) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.support.AppResourceCommon.getResource(AppResourceCommon.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-registry-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.service.DefaultAppRegistryService.getAppResource(DefaultAppRegistryService.java:266) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-registry-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.service.DefaultAppRegistryService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a8bae4.invoke() ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-registry-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.service.DefaultAppRegistryService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e83e4f6.getAppResource() ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-registry-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultSchedulerService.getTaskLauncherResource(DefaultSchedulerService.java:423) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultSchedulerService.schedule(DefaultSchedulerService.java:211) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.TaskSchedulerController.save(TaskSchedulerController.java:154) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:158) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]

I don't know what does it mean, I'm a newbie in Dataflow. I don't understand why he is trying to use Maven instead of a kubernetes deployer and why I get this error. Could someone provide me some more explanation?

I'm registering the applications as docker containers, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above log, it tries to download the maven resource when launching the scheduled task. This is because you registered your task applications as maven resources instead of docker images. You should register the docker images of the task applications on the Kubernetes environment.

Post 2.3.x release, SCDF launches the scheduled tasks via a task application called scheduler-task-launcher. By default this is set to use maven resource and you need to change this to use docker image. To change, you can set the property: spring.cloud.dataflow.task.scheduler-task-launcher-url to docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-scheduler-task-launcher:2.4.0.RELEASE

Comment: This is weird, I use docker images when registering the applications. How comes that now he is trying to deploy them as maver resources?

Comment: I see what's going on here. Post 2.3.x release, SCDF launches the scheduled tasks via a task application called `scheduler-task-launcher`. By default this is set to use maven resource and you need to change this to use docker image. To change, you can set the property: `spring.cloud.dataflow.task.scheduler-task-launcher-url` to `docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-scheduler-task-launcher:2.4.0.RELEASE`

Comment: Could you update your answer to include what you explained me in the comments? Just for having a more clear answer.